# Animation lag at the first run

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, lag

The search bar is animated using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)toggleSearchBar:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];
[applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:0.2];
[applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionPush];
[applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

if (self.searchBar.hidden) {

    self.searchBar.hidden = NO;
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [[searchBar layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionPush];

}else{

    self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [[searchBar layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionPush];

}
}
```

It works fine except the lag at the first run of the animation. Is there anyway to fix it? Any help will be appreciated:)

**Edit 1**

he leftBarButton is wired to `toggleSearchBar:` action. The app is loaded. The first animation is the first time the leftBarButton clicked.

Comment: When are you calling the animation for the first time? Is there a lot going on? Is the app still loading?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez The leftBarButton is wired to "toggleSearchBar" action. The app is loaded. The first animation is the first time the leftBarButton clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you show it off screen on loading the view controller... it's a bit hacky but it should do the trick.